# What is this jQuery function call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

The following is an implementation code from a free jquery gallery I am trying to implement.

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('#camera_wrap_2').camera({
    height: '400px',
    loader: 'bar',
    pagination: false,
    thumbnails: true
  });
});
</script>
```

What does this code do? I looked up methods to declare a function with jQuery, and none starts with

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('#camera_wrap_2').camera({
```

If anyone can explain what this does and point me to a resource on declaring such functions, i would be eternally grateful. Googling `jQuery(function(){` did not really work.

Moreover, 
This code only worked with the jquery file included - which is `jquery.min.js v.1.7.1` and `jquery.mobile.customized.min.js`

When I used the `jquery.min.js v.2.1.1` included with `foundations 5`, it produced an error in the `jquery.mobile.customized.min.js`

My guess is that the author had customized his mobile.js to work only with the specific jquery? I don't understand how that would happen though, even deprecated functions usually work.

Comment: That's a plugin method. Plugin allows you to bind custom method like you're seeing.

Comment: Read about plugins. And search for $.fn.camera = function() {};

Comment: Thanks, I am googling how to create jquery plugins right now - but are these jquery plugins tied to the jquery versions available? I am still at a loss as to why the code didnt work with the newer jquery version, even though I included his jquery.mobile.customized file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(function() {})` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function())`

NOTE: that is the same as:

`jQuery(function() {})` is shorthand for `jQuery(document).ready(function())`

The **$** is an alias for the **jQuery** object

it waits for all elements to be added to the DOM, so you can be sure they exist before calling methods upon them

Comment: Thank you!! I did not realize that $ is an alias.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add ...

Please to refer :
                      [jQuery-Library Source Code](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js)

In that library look at bottom-most comment section

> // Expose jQuery to the global object
>
> window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
>
> // Expose jQuery as an AMD module, but only for AMD loaders that...
>   ...
>
> ...
>
> ...

So you will get to know that window.jQuery is equivalent to jQuery which is equivalent to window.$ which is also equivalent to $.So use any one!!!

therefore,    window.jQuery=jQuery=window.$=$

Comment: Thank you! I am new to web development - trying not to mix syntaxes between php, css, html and js and jquery is confusing enough, without these languages having aliases and shortcuts :). Good to have the expert help in stackoverflow.